# 0x API get crypto price by URL Error: No Route matched

Tags: python, json

I'm working on 0x.org to get crypto price by URL.
Why following code won't work?

```
  https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/prices?sellToken=WETH
```

I get Error like this:

[image]

Comment: I test the url but get no response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So according to [API docs](https://0x.org/docs/) you must create an account and get an API key (0x-api-key) ([Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w46wH.png)) then add it to headers on every request.

As written [here](https://0x.org/docs/0x-price-api/api-references/get-swap-v1-price) you are required to define 3 url params:

- sellToken
- buyToken
- sellAmount

sellToken and buyToken should preferably have a valid address ([List of addresses](https://0x.org/docs/0x-price-api/api-references/overview#addresses-by-network)).

### Curl example

```
curl https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/price?sellToken=0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48&buyToken=0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2&sellAmount=10000000   --header '0x-api-key: <API_KEY>'
```

### Python example

```
import requests

response = requests.get(
    "https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/price",
    params={
        "sellToken": "0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48",
        "buyToken": "0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2",
        "sellAmount": "10000000",
    },
    headers={
        "0x-api-key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
    },
)
print(response.json())
```

### Result

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwIpL.png)